# Headphone Volume low despite being set at 100%

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

To give context, I would set the headset volume at 1-10 as it was easily loud enough. However, after logging on today, I found that even while at 100%, the volume was still quiet. I have no idea why, and it is rather irritating.

I have attached screenshots as I am new to Windows and maybe overlooking simple fixes/settings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/18KAQ.jpg

Comment: Have you tried different sounds/songs and different audio sources?

Comment: Have you checked the headset, particularly cord and plug, for damage?